# View LocalHost Via iPad

Tags: windows, ipad, iis, localhost

I would like to view my locally hosted website via an iPad or other mobile device.
I have seen that many other people have succeeded in doing this and am unsure where I'm going wrong.

I have window 7 with iis. I have tried my_ip_address/index.html in safari with and without windows firewall disabled.

I think port 80 is correct, however I also use phpmyadmin which uses port 3306 if that means anything. (I did try this though my_ip_address:3306/index.html but nothing changed)

I have also tried using the IPV4 address which gives me this error:

*Not Found
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.*

And IPV4 DNS Server (which is an almost identical ip address apart from the last digit) and this gives me the following error:

*Object Not Found
The requested URL '/index.asp' was not found on the RomPager server.
Return to last page*

I'm currently running around in circles so any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do this without any problems.

Try http://192.168.xxx.xxx:6969 on your laptop, does it work? Try it again with the iPad (obviously using your laptops ip address which I'm guessing looks like the above)

I've found it can be sensitive about the port number but I don't know why, 6969 did work for me.